# Beamer - split frame into two columns and adjust itemize environment

Tags: beamer, itemize, two-column, presentations, slideshow

I am experimenting with two-column layout for **beamer** slides. Currently I have the following slide:

```
\begin{frame}{Comparison}
    \pause
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
        Pros:
        \begin{itemize}[<+->]
            \pause
            \item 1
            \item 2
            \item 3
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
        Cons:
        \begin{itemize}[<+->]
            \item 1
            \item 2
            \item 3
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
\end{frame}
```

This gives me the following results:

1. Initial slide
   [image]
2. Only the "title" of the first column appears
   [image]
3. First bullet point in first column and the "title" of the second column appear simultaniously
   [image]
4. Later on all bullet points in first column are visible
   [image]
5. Starting with the bullet points in the second column
   [image]
6. The end...
   [image]

This behaviour looks bad so I was hoping someone here can give me a hand to try different ways of organizing this slide:

- **Version 1** - both "titles" appear simultaniously but first the list in the first column expands and then the one in the second
- **Version 2** - second column ("title" + bullet points) appears (not simultaneously of course) after all bullet points in first column are visible
- **Version 3** - both "titles" appear simultaneously and both lists expand gradually in sync (1 bullet point in Pros and 1 bullet point in Cons appear at the same time). This is very useful if both lists have the same number of items. This allows comparing items between the two lists if they are connected somehow

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to have fine control, specify the frames explicitly instead of using `\pause` and `<+->` (see version 3 below).

**Version 1:**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Comparison}
\pause
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
\onslide<2->%
        Pros:
\pause
        \begin{itemize}[<+->]
            \item 1
            \item 2
            \item 3
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}%
\onslide<2->%
        Cons:
        \begin{itemize}[<+->]
            \item 1
            \item 2
            \item 3
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Version 2:**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Comparison}
\pause
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
        Pros:
\pause
        \begin{itemize}[<+->]
            \item 1
            \item 2
            \item 3
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}%
\onslide<6->%
        Cons:
\pause
        \begin{itemize}[<+->]
            \item 1
            \item 2
            \item 3
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Version 3:**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Comparison}
\pause
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
        Pros:
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<3-> 1
            \item<4-> 2
            \item<5-> 3
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}%
        Cons:
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<3-> 1
            \item<4-> 2
            \item<5-> 3
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Works like a charm! For version two I did almost the same with the suggested `columns` environment.

Answer (score 8):

See, if the following solution gives what you looking for:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Comparison}
    \begin{columns}[t]
\begin{column}{0.48\linewidth}
        Pros:
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<1-> 1
            \item<2-> 2
            \item<3-> 3
        \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.48\linewidth}
        Cons:
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<1-> 1
            \item<2-> 2
            \item<3-> 3
        \end{itemize}
\end{column}
    \end{columns}    
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is it also possible to add the two other versions? (sorry for being so cheeky :P)

Comment: Using pauses (before second `itemize` and before second column) produces **Version 2**. Nice!

Comment: @rbaleksandar, meanwhile *gernot*  in his answer extend my answer with two more version, so there is no exist more possibilities anymore :)

Comment: Yeah, his answer appeared after I posted the comment. :P